# Office(Outlook) AddIn in C#

Tags: outlook-addin

Hei
I have created project for outlook Add-in in c#. I have to display the new menu item when i right click on one email or more .I have tried and have followed following link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_NewItemsMenuforMailModule

I dont know if iam getting the right "idMso" iam stuck also since i have outlook 2016 installed on my computer and when i create new project from visual studio it displays me template Outlook 2013 AddIn

Anybody have experience with that ?? shud i need to install the outlook2013 version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the right resource, just picked the wrong context to hook up with ("idMso"). Please look at the following:

- [Context Menu for a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforaMailItem)
- [Context Menu for Multiple Selected Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforMultipleSelectedItems)

> shud i need to install the outlook2013 version ?

You will be fine with your installation of Outlook 2016.

Comment: thank u but iam still not able to see when i right click on any email after running project

Comment: do u have any example how ThisAddIn_Startup look like ?

Comment: The same resource has the "ThisAddIn_Startup" method example: [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Sample Add-In). if you don't see context menu item(s), you most likely have an issue with ribbon xml. I would advise to verify again your ribbon xml. Have a lok on this QandA: [Add ContextMail Item Outlook 2013](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/061cb25a-f187-47bc-83be-116bbf4e3dde?category=vsto)

Comment: Hei do u have any example for outlook web add-In .I found the following link https://dev.office.com/hands-on-labs/1541   but when i run my project it open the outlook web but it dont have any ribbon bar soo i cannot find my add-In

Comment: i want to add one new item when right click on one or two emails not gtting what to use MessageReadCommandSurface or something else . alot of on net but didnt find relevant

Comment: @meer Outlook web add-ins uses Office.js API and do not run VSTO. Example of such add-in with ribbon extensability [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?product=outlook) and project itself is [outlook-add-in-command-demo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo). This add-ins are limited to work with one item only, you wil not have hooks on context menu. Also, if you have additional questions create the new one. Comments is not menu for QandA.

Comment: iam not able to ask more questions thats why sent to u here . do u have any mail ?